# YouTube API commentCount statistic not equal to number of actual comments retrieved

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to retrieve all the comments for a specific channel. Before pulling the comments, I checked the statistics of all the videos of the channel to see the number of comments per video I should expect. However, when I pulled the comments using commentThreads, the total number of comments I got did not equal the total number of comments I was expecting. To illustrate, I have a sample of 3 videos. I wrote a function to get the following:

comment_counter =number of comments as per video statistics

top_comments_count = actual number of top-level comments retrieved/counted

reply_count_info = number of replies as per top-level comment snippet

reply_counted = actual number of replies retrieved/counted

[Dataframe of comment counts per video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPNcD.png)

It looks like I am not getting all the replies to top-level comments. Any idea why this is happening?

Here is the code I used to get these numbers:

```
def count_video_comments(youtube,video_id):
comment_counter = 0 #number of comments as per video statistics
top_comments_count = 0 #actual number of top-level comments retrieved/counted
reply_count_info = 0 #number of replies as per top-level comment snippet
reply_counted = 0 #actual number of replies retrieved/counted

request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
    part="snippet,replies",
    videoId=video_id,
    order='time',
    maxResults=100)
response = request.execute()

request2 = youtube.videos().list(
    part="statistics",
    id=video_id)
response2 = request2.execute()

for video in response2['items']:
    comment_counter += int(video['statistics']['commentCount']) 

top_comments_count += len(response['items'])

for comment in response['items']:
    reply_count_info += comment['snippet']['totalReplyCount']

for comment in response['items']:
    if comment['snippet']['totalReplyCount'] !=0:
        reply_counted += len(comment['replies']['comments'])

next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

while next_page_token is not None:
    request = youtube.commentThreads().list(
        part="snippet,replies",
        videoId=video_id,
        maxResults=100,
        order='time',
        pageToken = next_page_token)
    response = request.execute()

    top_comments_count += len(response['items'])
    for comment in response['items']:
        reply_count_info += comment['snippet']['totalReplyCount']
    for comment in response['items']:
        if comment['snippet']['totalReplyCount'] !=0:
            reply_counted += len(comment['replies']['comments'])

    next_page_token = response.get('nextPageToken')

return (comment_counter,top_comments_count, reply_count_info, reply_counted)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `commentCount` obtained from the `statistics` of the `video` response contains the total of comments and its replies.

Quote from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?hl=en):

> **maxResults**    **`unsigned integer`**
>
> The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that
> should be returned in the result set.
>
> **Note**: This parameter is not supported for use in conjunction with the id parameter. Acceptable values are 1 to 100, **`inclusive`**. The
> default value is **20**.

The keyword here is **`inclusive`** = that means, it contains *both* the total of comments (*or top-level comment*) AND their *replies*.

You can try with this video id example: **`ouf0ozwnU84`**.

This video has 129 comments - value taken from its video statistics - [try it in the API feature](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus%2CtopicDetails%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22ouf0ozwnU84%22%5D%7D).

The same video has 89 comments - [you can try this endpoint here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A100%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22ouf0ozwnU84%22%7D) - and this video has 40 total replies - you can get this value by summing up the values from the **`totalReplyCount`** property (*in the CommentThreads endpoint*).

So, summing the 89 comments and the value 40 (*obtained from the sum of all **`totalReplyCount`** values*) gives = 129 comments (*the same as shown in the video's statistics*).

Comment: Thanks for response. 

I get that commentCount from the video statistics represent the total number top-level comments and the replies to the video. However, when I try to get the actual comments and replies so that I can save all of them in a data frame, I am not getting the same number as comments and replies I am expecting.

For the video id you provided as an example, I was able to retrieve all of the 89 top-level comments. However, when I pull the replies, out of the 40 expected replies, I am only getting 26 replies.

Comment: @kawaian in these lines: `if comment['snippet']['totalReplyCount'] !=0: reply_counted += len(comment['replies']['comments'])` - why not change it for `reply_counted += comment['snippet']['totalReplyCount']` instead? - probably I will give it a try later, but, I think you should try again with one video - I'm confused about why get `reply_count_info` and `reply_counted`, to be honest :)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Really appreciate it. I want to get the actual comments i.e. if a video has 3 comments (1 top-level comment with 2 replies), I want to store all 3 of them in a database so I can perform sentiment analysis. However, when I retrieve the actual comments, the number of  comments I get does not equal the number of comments that the video statistics indicates. If the totalReplyCount indicates that there are 2 replies, I want to be able to retrieve and store those 2 replies. But what is happening is totalReplyCount != actual replies retrieved.